# Python Selenium как найти элемен в модальном (всплывающем) окне?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

Как Найти в элемент в дочернем всплывающем окне (Modal Dialog) ?
используется Selenium ver 4.
Id элемента присутствует.

[image: find_element_in_other_wondow]

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

Comment: спасибо нашел )